# Why is prototype of my object undefined?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I created a `Car` object like this.

```
var Car = Object()
```

Then I added some properties to it like

```
Car.price = 5000;
Car.color = "red";
```

Then I created an instance of it like

```
var car1 = Object.create(Car);
```

What I don't understand is, when I call `car1.prototype` or `Car.prototype`, I get `undefined`.

According to what I've read, every Object is a prototype of something.

Can someone explain why it's "undefined"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> every Object is a prototype of something

No. Every object *has* a prototype (except the root object). However, only functions have a `prototype` **property**.

The value of that property will become the prototype of the objects that are created by calling the function as constructor function (e.g. `var obj1 = new Constr();`).

> What I don't understand is, when I call `car1.prototype` or `Car.prototype`, I get `undefined`.

As just explained, only *functions* have a `prototype` property. `car1` and `Car` are objects and therefore don't have such a property.

To get the prototype of an arbitrary object, you can use [**`Object.getPrototypeOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf):

```
var car1Prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(car1);
```

> Then I created an instance of it like `var car1 = Object.create(Car);`

You didn't create an instance of `Car`. If you created a new object and explicitly set its prototype to `Car`. Alternatively you could have defined `Car` as constructor function:

```
function Car(price, color) {
    this.price = price;
    this.color = color;
}

var car1 = new Car(5000, 'red');
```

Now that `Car` is a function,  `Car.prototype` would yield the prototype of `car1`, i.e.

```
Car.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(car1);
```

---

See also [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Answer (score 2):

Functions have prototypes. Object instances, like `car1`, don't.

It's correct to say that every object is a copy of some prototype. By default, objects are a copy of the prototype of the `Object` "function". However, object instances don't have a prototype themselves.

Think of a prototype as a "model" for a new Object. In Object Oriented languages, a `class` or a `struct` act like a strict model for new instances. That is, every instance of the `Car` class necessarily have `motor`, for instance. Likewise, in JavaScript, function prototypes act like the "model" for new instances of that function, but they are not strict. Once you create an instance from that model, you can add and remove members, because the language is dynamic.

**EDIT**

As Pointy clarified, it seems that object instances are not a copy of the "model" function `prototype` property. It seems that the prototype is copied to an internal object that is looked up when you try to access a property of the instantiated object.

Example:

```
var car1 = new Car();
// car1 now is not a copy of Car.prototype, but it has an internal object that is.
car1.motor = new V8Motor();
// even though motor is not a property of car1, this will work because JavaScript will find this property in the car1 prototype as it's not a member of the instance itself
```

Comment: Uhh ... that's not how prototypes work in JavaScript. The prototype is not *copied* to new objects.

Comment: How is it not copied?

Comment: The prototype reference is copied from the constructor function to an internal property of a newly-constructed object. When a property lookup is conducted, the prototype chain is consulted if the object does not directly have  a property of a particular name. [Here is a good blog post on the topic.](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/)

Comment: Your edit is still incorrect. Nothing is *copied*, the new object simply gets a *reference* to `Car.prototype`. Also, assigning `car1.motor` does not have anything to do with the prototype. It simply creates the property on the object.